# os.Mkdir versus syscall.Mkdir, what is the difference in Golang?

Tags: go

`os.Mkdir` and `syscall.Mkdir` both have same API in Golang

`syscall.Mkdir`:

```
func Mkdir(path string, mode uint32) (err error)
```

`os.Mkdir`:

```
func Mkdir(name string, perm FileMode) error
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Currently, [os.Mkdir() calls syscall.Mkdir()](https://golang.org/src/os/file.go?s=6935:6979#L220)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is the direct system call, platform dependent, probably faster/you can use all platform dependent bits (like sticky bit on Unix/Linux for instance)

The latter is the portable API which is supposed to work the same on every platform, note that second argument is no longer an anonymous integer but a constrained type.